# run discord bot inside flask

Tags: flask, discord.py, bots, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to have a strife bot that accesses the Flask Database (Flask SQLAlchemy). I would like to know if there is a way to make the Discord bot run and managed via the Flask Web Application, how to connect the two so that they can interact with each other
Thanks, Regard

here is my flask configuration

```
# bot Client Config
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', case_insensitive=True)

# Load Token Config
load_dotenv('.env')

# Token Config
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

# Picture Extension
pict_ext = ('.jpg','.png','.jpeg')
#

# Flask Configuration
def create_app(script_info=None):
    # environtment configurations

    # module import
    from projects.dashboard.views import dashboard_blueprint

    # initialize app
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

    # register blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(dashboard_blueprint)

    return app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

running discord bot in the separate thread using thread module like this

```py
# thread function
def flask_thread(func):
    thread = Thread(target=func)
    print('Start Separate Thread From Bot')
    thread.start()
```

then add it to the main file

```py
# main file

# function run flask with separate Thread
def run():
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=10000, use_reloader=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_thread(func=run)
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

running with command

```sh
python main.py
```

and see http://localhost:10000 in your browser